# .gitignore Question

Tags: gitignore

I originally checked in a file and pulled it to a development server. Now, I no longer want to to track them because the settings are different for every computer. After the first pull I changed a few lines.

In my .gitignore file I have this:

```
config/hostname.rb
```

Now, whenever I `git pull` on the development server I get an error like this:

```
error: Your local changes to 'config/hostname.rb' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# ignore changes in a working tree file
git update-index --assume-unchanged config/hostname.rb
```

Comment: I ran this on my laptop and the dev server. It worked. But do I need to run on both?

Comment: You can only do it on a local repo you want to ignore existing files (that are already managed by git). I don't think it does anything in bare repositories as they lack a working tree.